# Compile Error: Next without FOR Filtering each ws by month

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, filter

I am trying to use a for loop to filter each ws in this workbook by the current month. Here is where it stands right now

```
    Sub curmonth()

Dim ws As Worksheet

On Error Resume Next

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Visible Then

 ' filter each worksheet by current month
    Range("A:G").AutoFilter Field:=5, Operator:=xlAnd, _
 Criteria1:=">" & Application.EoMonth(Now, -1), _
 Criteria2:="<=" & Application.EoMonth(Now, 0)



Next ws
On Error GoTo 0


End Sub
```

It keeps giving me the error "Compile Error: Next without FOR", which is puzzling for me because there is indeed a next and a for.

Comment: Try putting in an `End If`.

Comment: You miss the `End If` statement. Also, change the `Range("A:G")...` to `ws.Range("A:G")...`

Comment: @RafaelMatos got time to make that an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've missed the `End If` statement. Also, change the `Range("A:G")...` to `ws.Range("A:G")...`. With these changes, your `For` loop should be:

```
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Visible Then

        ' filter each worksheet by current month
        ws.Range("A:G").AutoFilter Field:=5, Operator:=xlAnd, _
            Criteria1:=">" & Application.EoMonth(Now, -1), _
            Criteria2:="<=" & Application.EoMonth(Now, 0)
    End If
Next ws
```

Answer (score 0):

usually it means an other nesting code (select case, if, do while, with...) is not finished, but you already loop\stop the precedent one.

In your case , you are missing an end if